# Subalgebra membership test

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $I$ be an ideal. Let $R= K[g_1 + I,\dots, g_n+I]$ be a sub-algebra of the affine K-algebra $A=K[y_1,\dots, y_m]/I$ for some $g_i\in K[y_1,\dots, y_m]$. Let $x_1,\dots, x_n$ be some aditional indeterminates, and let $J:= (I\cup \{g_1-x_1,\dots,g_n-x_n \})_{K[x_1,\dots, x_n,y_1,\dots, y_n]}$. I have show the subalgebra membership test. While doing this, I encountered some problems.

I have two questions:

a. if $h\in K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ then why $h-h(g_1,\dots, g_n)\in J$?

b. Why if $f+I=h(g_1+I,\dots,g_n+I)$ then $f-h\in J$?

Comment: a. We have $(g_i-x_i) \mid (g_i^n-x_i^n)$.

Comment: (a) Write $h-h(g_1,...,g_n)=h-h((g_1-x_1)+x_1,...,(g_n-x_n)+x_n)$ and expand the second term in powers of the $x_i$ that are outside of the parentheses. This is just Taylor expansion, at the point $(x_1,...,x_n)$ with increment $(g_1-x_1,...,g_n-x_n)$. The $h$ cancels and everything else is in the ideal generated by the $g_i-x_i$. (b) the same idea.

Comment: Alternatively, or equivalently, working modulo $J$, one has that $g_i=x_i$. So, $h(x_1,...,x_n)-h(g_1,...,g_n)=h(x_1,...,x_n)-h(x_1,...,x_n)=0$.